# I want to create a series of fullwidth ion-cards populated through an array of objects

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I want to iterate through an array of objects to create a series of FULLWIDTH (or halfwidth with the last one centered if count is an odd number) cards.

I have create a component which contains the card layout and am iterating through an the array using *ngFor but the col size does not seem to be affected regardless of what attributes i feed it or where I place it (within or outside the loop). The cards just size dynamically according to the text

```
<ion-row>
  <app-artist-view *ngFor="let deal of loadedEvent.deals" [deal]='deal'></app-artist-view>
</ion-row>
```

```
<ion-col size = "12"> 
  <ion-card>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label  class="ion-text-center">{{deal.title}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>


    <ion-card-content class="ion-text-center">

      <ion-card-subtitle>Name: {{deal.talent.name}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{deal.performanceType}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Length: {{deal.performanceLength}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Status: {{deal.status}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Value: {{deal.value}}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-col>
```

The cards size dynamically according to the text instead of remaining fullwidth for each component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flex-boxing :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px;
  height: 64px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 24px);
  background: coral;
  border: 1px solid teal;
  margin: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You have to calculate the width of a flexed element because the gutter must be taken into consideration when flexing the element. There's several ways of doing this, but this is the quickest one.

Comment: not quite working since im using the ion-card but it's a good start, i'll keep working with this till i get it to workout, thanks

Comment: The ionic card does not change the fact that HTML manages flex boxing : simply try to use `display: block` on them !